# WSDL to Java -client creation error

Tags: xsd, axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to create a web service from the WSDL but is repeatedly giving me the following error. Tried refreshing `axis.jar` in the build path but is still giving same error whereas I have another WSDL and client is very well being generated for the same.

Anyone here who has encountered something similar?

> IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  WSDLException (at
>   /definitions/types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error
>   occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at
>   '@sp.schema.url@/FinancialStatement.xsd', relative to
>   'file:/C:/hrishi_workspace/findata/web/wsdl/FinancialStatement.wsdl'.:
>   This file was not found:
>   file:/C:/hrishi_workspace/findata/web/wsdl/@sp.schema.url@/FinancialStatement.xsd:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found:
>   file:/C:/hrishi_workspace/findata/web/wsdl/@sp.schema.url@/FinancialStatement.xsd
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(Unknown Source)
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(Unknown Source)
>     at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:516)
>     at
>   org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.populate(SymbolTable.java:495)
>     at org.apache.axis.wsdl.gen.Parser$WSDLRunnable.run(Parser.java:361)

Thanks.

Rishi

Comment: It says a file not found. Do you have it? Where is it referenced from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your file:/C:/hrishi_workspace/findata/web/wsdl/FinancialStatement.wsdl is making a reference to an external schema file. If you look inside that WSDL file, under the definitions/types/xsd:schema element, you'll have one or more xsd:include and/or xsd:import. These elements may have a schemaLocation attribute; look for the one that ends in *FinancialStatement.xsd*; I suspect it has the **@sp.schema.url@** in there which to me looks like a placeholder that is probably supposed to be changed by your build script or something else... Replace that with the relative path between the WSDL and XSD; if they are in the same folder, simply use the XSD file name. It should take care of the error. Once it works, you should try to understand what's with that placeholder, and maybe figure out what you need to configure in your particular environment to make it work like that...